# PasswordSignInAsync and CreateAsync without Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

`SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` checks user if present in database and signs in. `await UserManager.CreateAsync` creates new user in database. `await SignInManager.SignInAsync` signs in the user.

Correct me if I'm wrong but it trivial for this question. How to implement those functionalities when we are not using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Are you planning to use aspnet identity membership schema or custom authentication & authorization? Depends on that. Those methods out of box over the schema, otherwise you need to have information how to authorize

Comment: @PranavSingh is right: The question is, agains what do want to authorize?

Comment: @PranavSingh I am not using custom authentication but asp.net identity which is by default in sample application.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to implement those method even if you're not using EF

You can rely to asp.net identity by registering a custom class with a IUserStore and call them to use your own database access

I've followed this article and the membership works even with my own written data access layer:

https://markjohnson.io/articles/asp-net-core-identity-without-entity-framework/

Basically you have to :

1. write your db access (of course)
2. create a model for the user (and for the role, etc.)
3. create a UserStore that implements IUserStore, handling YourCustomModel methods
4. add the UserStore as a service in app's Startup

You can then refer to identity managers in your Controller thanks to dependency injection

```
    private readonly UserManager<YourCustomModel> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<YourCustomModel> _signInManager;

    public YourCustomController(
        UserManager<YourCustomModel> userManager,
        SignInManager<YourCustomModel> signInManager
        )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

and in your actions use them to invoke identity methods :

```
    var uModel = YourCustomModel.Static.SelectByEmail(vModel.Email);

    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(uModel, vModel.Password,
                                  vModel.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    if (result.Succeeded) ...
```

Answer (score -1):

**SignInAsync method instead and create a user object in memory.**

```
var userPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(new 
   ApplicationUser
           {
                  Id = 1,
                  UserName = viewModel.UserName,
                  Email = viewModel.UserName,
                  SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
           });
     foreach(var claim in userPrincipal.Claims)
     {
            appUser.Claims.Add(new ApplicationUserClaim { UserId = appUser.Id, 
            ClaimType = claim.Type, ClaimValue = claim.Value });
     }
     await _signInManager.SignInAsync(appUser, viewModel.RememberMe);
```

Comment: SignInManager.SignInAsync still calls the database. This answer is wrong.